# SQL get connections from one column to itself through second column

Tags: sql, t-sql

SQL, one table, two columns of data, `person` and `mailbox`. Each person may have many mailboxes, each mailbox may have many people. I want to get the number of people connected to other people through a mailbox:

```
person | mailboxCount | aggregatePersonCount
```

I have a bad feeling this has been solved elsewhere here, but I cannot think of what the terminology could be. For all the big, complicated stored procs and queries I've written, this simple two-column analysis has me stumped.

Table structure:

```
person | mailbox
```

I have the first two columns:

```
SELECT a.person, count(a.mailbox) mailboxCount
FROM [EmailGroupAnalysis].[dbo].[AnalysisTests] a
GROUP BY a.person
order by mailboxCount desc
```

Comment: How are "people connected to other people through a mailbox" in terms of your data? A recursive solution using a Common Table Expression (CTE) may be appropriate. Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self join:

```
select a.person, count(distinct a.mailbox) as mailboxCount,
       count(distinct a2.person) as mailboxConnectedPersons
from [EmailGroupAnalysis].[dbo].[AnalysisTests] a left join
     [EmailGroupAnalysis].[dbo].[AnalysisTests] a2 
     on a.mailbox = a2.mailbox 
group by a.person
order by mailboxCount desc;
```

Note:  This counts the original person.  You can subtract 1 to avoid that.